# Check if a machine on local network is available with PHP

Tags: php, terminal, wake-on-lan

I have a PHP app runing on local network server (Mac Mini server with OS X Lion). There are several local clients (also Macs) accessing this app. Client machines are put to sleep from time to time. I need to be able to check from PHP server if the local clients are running (wake) or in sleep mode.

I have been successful of doing this with AJAX polling script, where I periodically ping the local machines and display status of a local machine in PHP app. The problem I have is that PING command initiates wake-on-lan on client machines if they are in sleep mode, and this is something I do not want. I would just like to see the status without waking the machine.

Can this be done?

Comment: So you're searching for a network packet that gets responded to but doesn't trigger wake-on-lan? I don't think there is.

Comment: You could let the machines ping the server. If they stop responding, they're down.

Comment: Is installing/running something at the client machines an option?

Comment: @JanDvorak correct I have option to install SW on client machines... I was also thinking about clients pinging server and if stop responding then mark they are offline, but this is not best solution.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to stick to the dead man's switch.

Answer (score 1):

check

> pmset -g | grep hibernatemode
>
> http://www.tuaw.com/2010/10/20/safesleep-lets-you-use-safe-sleep-on-demand-on-your-mac/

Comment: OK `pmset -g | grep hibernatemode` will get me a hibernation mode on local compuer. I can't call this status for remote machine if it is in sleep correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to correctly configure the Wake-on-lan for those machines. Aparently they get awakened for every packet, which is probably not what you require. Usually WoL is configured to wake only on [Magic Packet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_packet) (on Windows it can be configured in Device Manager in the properties of network card driver). Then you will be able to use ping (or any other type of network traffic) to check if PC is online.